# Okta redirect dynamic relay state

Tags: saml, okta

When using the Okta single sign-in with link redirect ( rather than send + generate a SAML request object ), is it possible to dynamically include the relay state? ( e.x. include a RelayState header or querystring )

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Assuming you are talking about this:
[Retrieving a session cookie by visiting a session redirect link](http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/session_cookie.html#retrieving-a-session-cookie-by-visiting-a-session-redirect-link)

The way I've done it is as follows:

```
appSSOUrl = 'https://your.okta.com/app/identifier/sso/saml'
RelayStateValue = URLENCODE(desired relay state here)
redirectUrl = URLENCODE(appSSOUrl + '?RelayState=' + RelayStateValue)
```

Sending the userAgent to

```
https://your.okta.com/login/sessionCookieRedirect?token={cookieToken}&redirectUrl={redirectUrl}
```

Here {redirectUrl} is a URL encoded version of your okta application SSO URL ? appended with a RelayState parameter. The Value of that parameter is the URL encoded relaystate you dynamically generated before the redirect.

The URL encoding may not be mandatory but i had good results doing it that way.

the resulting redirect URL is a doozy but it works.

```
https://your.okta.com/login/sessionCookieRedirect?token=00FAyayhEPQj3O7czF192BaEzjWhGjOSKk7f4QNRfe&redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fyour.okta.com%2Fapp%2Fidentifier%2Fsso%2Fsaml%3FRelayState%3DParam1%253Dvalue1%2526param2%253Dvalue2%2526param3%253Dvalue3
```

Comment: I think using cookies is one valid approach, though I was looking at a straight SAML response w/o the cookie, check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

By adding a querystring output to the redirect link

https://your.okta.com/.../sso/saml?RelayState=/param1/param2

the output Relay State will be sent in the return message body

{
 SAMLResponse: ...,
 RelayState: "/param1/param2"
}

Comment: Can I send a full-fledged URL in relaystate? I want to send it to a different domain after successful login.